# Draw horizontal lines each certain values - Pine editor

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to do a script in Pine to repeat the drawing of horizontal lines every certain values

Yellow line should be repeated every 200 points (in this exmple start in 11600)
Green line is drawn 50 points below the yellow line (11540 and 11550)
Red line is drawn 30 points above the yellow line (11630 and 11640)

````
LevelStart = hline(11600, title = "Levelstart", color = color.yellow, linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth = 1) 
h1 = hline(11550) 
h2 = hline(11540) 
fill(h1, h2, color=color.new(color.green, 90)) 
h3 = hline(11630) 
h4 = hline(11640) 
fill(h3, h4, color=color.new(color.red, 90)) 
plot(close)```

It is the first time that I use pine editor
I can draw the 3 basic lines but I don´t know how to repeat them in the chart


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSXxO.png
````

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far and where you need help.

Comment: study(shorttitle="Test", title="Test", overlay=true)
LevelStart = hline(11600, title = "Levelstart", color = color.yellow, linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth = 1)
h1 = hline(11550)
h2 = hline(11540)
fill(h1, h2,  color=color.new(color.green, 90))
h3 = hline(11630)
h4 = hline(11640)
fill(h3, h4, color=color.new(color.red, 90))
plot(close)

Comment: Please don't add your code as a comment. Instead, edit your original question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

your code works fine
[image]

```
//@version=4

study(shorttitle="Test", title="Test", overlay=true)

LevelStart = hline(11600, title = "Levelstart", color = color.yellow, linestyle = hline.style_dotted, linewidth = 1) 
h1 = hline(11550) 
h2 = hline(11540) 
fill(h1, h2, color=color.new(color.green, 90)) 
h3 = hline(11630) 
h4 = hline(11640) 
fill(h3, h4, color=color.new(color.red, 90)) 
plot(close)
```

What is the question?

Comment: I need to repeat the values in the chart, line yellow -200 / +200 points (11200 11400 11600 11800 1200 etc), and the same with red and green